# DIV comment tags in html code - purpose and automation?

Tags: html, tags, comments

When looking at the codes of most professional websites, I see that the html code is usually commented like this:

```
<!-- END DIV Main Menu -->,
```

etc which is very helpful.

2 questions though:

- Does it have other purpose than giving an indication of what DIV is closed?
- Is there a way to get these types of comments added automatically? (I'm using coda 2)
  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments only serve the purpose of helping the designer of the webpage to tell which tag is being closed.

You can try using the comment-banner plugin:

<s>http://www.laymance.com/products/coda-plugins/#comment-banner</s>

Updated Link: https://panic.com/coda/plugins.php?id=117

Comment: dead link, new link?

Answer (score 3):

Commenting is essential part of coding including `div` open/close:

- It allows to leave some important information about the code. Which can make remind of something useful
- Allow to provide information who reviewed the code and about author
- Also chat with developers working on same
- comment some part of code for later use
- show warnings: `<!-- DO NOT EDIT THIS PAGE, IT'S AUTO-GENERATED BY A SCRIPT -->`
- content management etc..

Answer (score 1):

yes, in this case, there will be a closing tag above the comment '`</div>`' which will indicate that the div closed is the main menu div.
Also, i think you can add snippets in coda to automatically generate the opening and closing tag of divs and add the above comment when we open a div.